# Showing Cached files when no Internet Access in Ionic Framework/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

I understand that Ionic Framework has its built-in nav-view caching capability using `<ion-view cache-view="true">`. But is it possible to show the cached page only when no internet connection is detected? Or is this possible using AngularJS' approach?

Comment: I cache by storing all $http requests in local storage.  Then if the $http error is ever triggered, it will use the data found in local storage rather than what is obtained from the server.  See here if you can't visualize this process. https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/saving-data-with-ionicframework/

Comment: Oh, hello Nic! I read a lot of your articles. Very useful. But I have question, all my $http requests contains images(image link then viewed using `<img src="{{}}"/>`) from my server. Is it possible to view it on my app without internet using your method? I'm afraid it may break.

Comment: Also, I think localStorage is very limited in size.

Comment: I'm personally not familiar with any asset caching libraries and yes local storage will have size constraints, but do you really plan on caching more than 2 to 5MB of string data?  If no asset caching libraries exist, you may want to check out the File plugins and download them to your device SD card.

Comment: angular image-cache is there through that you can cache the files

Comment: I think ionic's cache-view="" stops the page (& controller) getting destroyed when you navigate away to prevent having to reinitialize it next time that view is rendered (eg. when the user hits back). It's nothing to do with the browser's HTTP caching over the network.

Comment: So did you manage to find an answer ?